# Как заполнить двумерный массив уникальными случайными числами С++?

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void main()
 {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
  srand(time(NULL));

  int const ROW = 3, COL = 3;
  int arr[ROW][COL];

  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
      {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 9;
       }
     }

  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
     {
        cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
      }
     cout << endl;
    }
 cout << endl;
 system("pause");
 }
```

Компилятор выдает матрицу с повторяющимися значениями. Как расположить их случайным образом, чтобы при этом они не повторялись?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ildar в том то и дело, что не выходит. Я из совсем зеленых. В сети не нашел решения, которое было бы понятно

Comment: @Ildar сортировка массива

Comment: Диапазон, которому должны принадлежать случайные числа, оговаривается?

Comment: Ну, например, уникально заполнить массив в 200 элементов случайными числами от 1 до 100 не получится :) А как вариант - заполните его последовательными числами (точно уникальны :)) и перемешайте...

Comment: @AnT массив 3х3 числа от 1 до 9

Comment: "числа от 1 до 9"??? То есть вам нужна случайная перестановка? И это самое главное, ключевое (!) требование задачи даже не упомянуто в вопросе??? Значит так: либо немедленно редактируйте вопрос, либо немедленно удаляйте его и задавайте новый.

Comment: @AnT я просто хочу, чтобы компилятор вывел в консоли массив 3х3 заполненный случайным образом, но без повторений

Comment: @bomod1337: Что??? Вы только что сказали, что вам надо заполнить массив именно числами от 1 до 9. Просто "заполнить случайным образом без повторений"  и "заполнить случайным образом числами от 1 до 9 без повторений" - это две совершенно разные, не имеющие ничего общего задачи. Если вам нужно "именно числами от 1 до 9" - это должно быть немедленно помещено в вопрос. Не в комментарии, а в вопрос. И немедленно.

Comment: заполните массив с инкрементом и перемешайте его [Случайные перестановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб - сдампите данные в один вектор и прогоните через unique - если он вернет что-то отличное от std::end - то есть дубликаты

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937_64 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> uid(0, 5);
    auto rand_gen{std::bind(uid, generator)};

    std::vector<int> r_vec;
    r_vec.resize(10);
    std::generate(std::begin(r_vec), std::end(r_vec), rand_gen);

    for (auto v : r_vec) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }

    auto tmp = r_vec;

    std::sort(std::begin(tmp), std::end(tmp));

    auto last = std::unique(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());

    if (last != std::end(tmp)) {
        std::cout << "no unique" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "unique" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Основное здесь - требование уникальности. Решается заменой вызова rand() на некий свой генератор (может быть основан на rand()), дополненный памятью на уже выданные значения и правилом выбора следующего при конфликте. Судя по вашему коду, диапазон случайных чисел - от 0 до 8 включительно, для запоминания хватит булевого массива из девяти элементов. Если rand() выдал вновь уже использованную позицию, то простейшим правилом решения конфликта может быть выдача следующей по модулю 9 свободной позиции.